Can we idiomatically say "Jack is an ordered person" to mean he is an organized person?
Is it natural to say someone is "ordered" in order to mean s/he is a well-organized person. From what I saw in the dictionaries, "orderly" has more of a meaning like "peaceful/well-behaved" when used to modify a person. And again according to dictionaries, we can call a place or someone's life "ordered", but I wonder if it would be natural among native English speakers to directly call a person "ordered" as in:

Jack is an ordered person/Jack is ordered.

While I know that it is a hundred percent okay to say something in the likes of

Jack leads an ordered life.


Orderly would  be a better choice to describe a person.

Kate, thanks, but the dictionaries I checked say "orderly" means "peaceful/well-behaved" when used to describe a person rather than mean "well-organized." I don't think "well-organized/organized" and "well-behaved" have the same meaning.

Well, the link I found also gives : observant of or governed by system or method, as persons or the mind.

An orderly group of people means they're peaceful and well-behaved, but when applied to a single person (nt so common) it would normally mean "methodical, well-organized".

This question would be better asked on english.stackexchange.com

organized or well-organized is another alternative, if you don't like orderly (whose meanings include "regulated", "methodical").

If, by idiomatic, you mean "what the average person would say", then no. But if, by idiomatic, what you mean is "what an intelligent native speaker might say, expecting to be understood by other intelligent native speakers, then yes.
ordered meaning "not haphazard, the opposite of slovenly, meticulous, scrupulous" is a word that isn't used in that sense in the meaty part of the bell curve.
P.S. The word ordered in this sense is used mainly in philosophical and religious writing and refers to  a kind of mental or spiritual virtue that governs a person's choices and behavior in all spheres of activity.

There's scope for ambiguity if you say that a single person is "orderly". He might be neat and tidy, but you might mean - or be understood to mean - that he's well-behaved and peaceful (that's the normal meaning of an orderly crowd).
It's probably better to avoid derivatives of order and go for methodical...

I haven't included He is ordered in the above chart, because almost all matches would be irrelevant "false positives" (He is ordered to do something).
